# NHibernate / LINQ: how to write this JOIN query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, linq-to-nhibernate

I got an entity E having a many-to-many relation with entity F.
Now i want to count all instances of E which are related to a certain instance of F.

In good old HQL-times, I used the following query:

```
select count(*) from E e inner join e.fCollection f where f.id = :id
```

:id is the primary key of the relevant F instance. 
e.fCollection is the collection holding all F instances, e is related to.

With NH-to-LINQ, it doesn't seem possible to join with fCollection.

Any ideas? :)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
e.Count(x => x.fCollection.Any(y => y.id == id));
```

This returns the number of `e`s with at least one collection item with the specified id.
If you want the number of collection items that have the specified id, use this:

```
e.fCollection.Count(x => x.id == id);
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I'd vote you up but my reputation is not high enough :(

Comment: @user1447851: No problem. I upvoted your question, so you got some reputation. :-) Accepting my answer using the checkmark to the left will give you another two rep.